# Gif cursor not working

Tags: java, cursor

Hello I have this piece of code to convert the cursor to a gif image that I have.

```
Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Image welcomePanel_Alien_Image = toolkit.getImage("src/Images/loading.gif");
        Cursor welcomePanel_Alien_Cursor = toolkit.createCustomCursor
        (welcomePanel_Alien_Image , new Point(welcomePanel.getX(), 
         welcomePanel.getY()), "img");

         welcomePanel.setCursor (transparentCursor);
```

but the only thing is the program run without displaying anything at all ( Note the program runs perfectly with png image format ). So one of the solution I read on here it says that I need to replace this :

```
Image welcomePanel_Alien_Image = toolkit.getImage("src/Images/loading.gif");
```

with this :

```
 Image image = toolkit.getImage(getClass().getResource("pencil.gif"));
```

but when I do that I get this error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   sun.awt.SunToolkit.getImageFromHash(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.awt.SunToolkit.getImage(Unknown Source)

Any Help would be appreciated

Comment: `src/Images/loading.gif` should be something more like `/Images/loading.gif` assuming the image name `loading.gif` is in the `images` directory and they are stored correctly within the context of the application's class path (ie bundled within the Jar) - I'd also be interested in knowing if it's actually possible for the OS to display a GIF based cursor

Comment: I changed it to `/Images/loading.gif` and now I don't get an error  but I got the same problem which I had fist which is that the program dies not display anything. Any ideas of why this is happening ?

Comment: The "hotspot" offset (`new Point(welcomePanel.getX(), welcomePanel.getY())`) is not the offset of the component, but the offset within the image at which the "click" action occurs - Take a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483732/mouse-jumping-when-i-enter-a-label/19483764#19483764) for more details

Comment: And [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23902159/java-custom-cursor-wont-work-on-new-computer/23902201#23902201)

Comment: @MadProgrammer But the thing is that the program does not run at all. Do you know how to fix it ? thanks

Comment: @MadProgrammer But how come it works for normal png image. I only have problem for gif files. When I use png the cursor is changed to the icon I have when I am at the welcome panel

Comment: Consider providing a runnable [example which demonstrates your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - as I said, the OS my not be capable for display GIF image as a cursor

Comment: I am using Windows 10, The time it would take me to make an example that can be demonstrated will be the same as me solving this issue. I understand that you need the code to solve it, I was just wondering if some has faced the same problem before so that they could help immediately. Anyways, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so, this is probably a good indication that I need to go back to bed

```
Image welcomePanel_Alien_Image = toolkit.getImage("src/Images/loading.gif");
```

Should probably become

```
Image welcomePanel_Alien_Image = toolkit.getImage(getClass().getResource("/Images/loading.gif"));
```

Two things:

1. `getImage(String)` assumes that the value is a "file" on the file system
2. Once built, the resource will no longer be accessible from the `src` directory nor referenced as a "file"

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23902159/java-custom-cursor-wont-work-on-new-computer/23902201#23902201) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483732/mouse-jumping-when-i-enter-a-label/19483764#19483764), the `hotspot` parameter describes the offset from within the image at which a "click" point is generating. So you should most definitely not use `new Point(welcomePanel.getX(), welcomePanel.getY())` because that's likely to cause no end of weird results.

Under Windows, I believe you stuck to a cursor size of 32x32, might have changed for Windows 10/Java 8+, but I've not tested it

For this example I used...

[image: Animated GIF] and [image: PNG] as my test cursors.

The ONLY way I was able to get the GIF to display was to use `ImageIO.read` to load it, which meant that it would not animate.  Attempting to load the image with `ImageIcon` or `Toolkit#createImage` failed to display anything, I even employed a `MediaTracker` to try and ensure the image was loaded before creating the cursor

```
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.MediaTracker;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            JButton normal = new JButton("Normal");
            JButton gif = new JButton("GIF");
            JButton png = new JButton("PNG");

            add(normal);
            add(gif);
            add(png);

            normal.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
                }
            });

            gif.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
//                    try {
//                        Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(getClass().getResource("/images/cursor.gif"));
//                        MediaTracker mt = new MediaTracker(TestPane.this);
//                        mt.addImage(image, 1);
//                        mt.waitForAll();
//                        Cursor cursor = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(image, new Point(0, 0), "gifCursor");
//                        
//                        setCursor(cursor);
//                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
//                        ex.printStackTrace();
//                    }
                    try {
                        Image image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/cursor.gif"));
                        Cursor cursor = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(image, new Point(0, 0), "gifCursor");

                        setCursor(cursor);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            png.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    try {
                        Image image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/cursor.png"));
                        Cursor cursor = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(image, new Point(0, 0), "pngCursor");

                        setCursor(cursor);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: It would have been perfect if the program animated the GIF. But I have learnt new things from ur answer. Thanks, I appreciate it :) Have a good night ;D